# service fabric - Reverse proxy - instance count

Tags: reverse-proxy, azure-service-fabric

I'm facing 1 issue related to reverse proxy. I have a webAPI as stateless service communicating with other mico services. IN our UAT environment (on Premises) we have configured instance count for WebAPI service as 3, but after this my reverse proxy calls are not working. It is working only in case of instance count as 1. Please let me know if I'm missing anything. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Gaurav, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you paste the code you have so far, the one that works and the one that doesn't?

Comment: How many nodes does your UAT cluster have? It should be at least 3 to run 3 Web Api instances.

Comment: @PaulaHasstenteufel it works when I have just 1 instance of my service in config.
 <Parameter Name="MyWebApi_InstanceCount" Value="1" /> -- working
<Parameter Name="MyWebApi_InstanceCount" Value="3" /> -- not working

Comment: @LoekD there are 3 nodes in UAT, but my reverse proxy works only if I specify Instance count as 1.
 <Parameter Name="MyWebApi_InstanceCount" Value="1" /> -- working <Parameter Name="MyWebApi_InstanceCount" Value="3" /> -- not working

Comment: Just to add, I'm calling my webapi using reverse proxy like this.
http://vmsfab01:19081/MyApiUATApplication/MyWebApi/api/UserProfile/Get